How to access the list element in DMN?
DMN contains 3 lists. taxRate, taxAmount and taxPremium.
   "taxablePremium": [
        1000,
        1500,
        2000
    ],
    "taxRate": [
        5.000,
        5.000,
        5.000
    ],
    "taxAmount": [
        100,
        150,
        200
    ]

The condition is to compare the user input of taxAmount to the calculated taxAmount value using a simple formula.
for X in 1..count(taxablePremium) return if taxAmount[X] != ((taxRate[X] * taxablePremium[X]) / 100) then "Tax Amount must equal the calculated value" else "Valid".
Getting the following error:
"dmn-evaluation-result" : {
      "messages" : [ {
        "dmn-message-severity" : "ERROR",
        "message" : **"Error evaluating Decision node 'Check Taxable Amount': null"**,
        "message-type" : "ERROR_EVAL_NODE"


probably it would help to share whole DMN model you have to understand better the problem. The only point that I have is that for cycle will return array of values not a single one. In the attached screenshot I updated your example just slightly, not using string as result but boolean and I am returning single value.
ps. ignore the New Input Data field, it is just 'hack' to fire the DMN Runner and obtain this screenshot.

